# How to set a variable to a random value with bash

Tags: command-line, bash

In a program, I need to set a variable to a random value of either 0 or 1.

I can't figure out how to do it and Google has failed me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One easy method is to use `$RANDOM` to retrieve a pseudorandom 16 bit integer number in the range [0; 32767]. You can simply convert that to [0; 1] by calculating modulo 2 of the random number:

```
echo $(( $RANDOM % 2 ))
```

More information about Bash's `$RANDOM`: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html

With that simple construct you can easily build powerful scripts using randomness, like in this comic...

[image: Commit Strip - Russian Roulette]

Comment: The pedant in me feels the need to point out that the chosen production server destroying command won't do anything without `--no-preserve-root` - so maybe not the game of Russian Roulette they were hoping for...

Comment: @BoristheSpider they are using the antiquated `$[]` syntax - who knows whether their `rm` had that `--no-preserve-root` feature?

Comment: @BoristheSpider My interpretation of the comic is that, when they see the message `rm: it is dangerous to operate recursively on '/'` `rm: use --no-preserve-root to override this failsafe`, they hang their head low and, knowing they have lost the game, proceed to erase their disk with `dd`, out of honor.

Comment: @EliahKagan ah, seppuku. Understood.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: The `--no-preserve-root` got only implemented "lately".  Have no information on when it was implemented, but IIRC it is only a few years old. And that's a tiny amount when it comes to Linux. Here is a ticket about this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/coreutils/+bug/174283

Comment: A `%2` (MOD 2) is exactly equivalent to `&1` (bitwise AND 1). Both will get the last bit of the number (even or odd). But AND is looot faster. So: use `echo $(( $RANDOM & 1 ))`.

Answer (score 15):

You could use `shuf`

```
DESCRIPTION
     Write a random permutation of the input lines to standard output.

     -i, --input-range=LO-HI
            treat each number LO through HI as an input line
     -n, --head-count=COUNT
            output at most COUNT lines
```

Example:

```
$ foo=$(shuf -i0-1 -n1)
$ echo $foo
1
$ foo=$(shuf -i0-1 -n1)
$ echo $foo
0
$ foo=$(shuf -i0-1 -n1)
$ echo $foo
0
$ foo=$(shuf -i0-1 -n1)
$ echo $foo
1
```

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
#!/bin/bash
r=$(($RANDOM % 2))
echo $r
```

Or even:

```
r=$(($(od -An -N1 -i /dev/random) % 2))
```

Or perhaps:

```
r=$(seq 0 1 | sort -R  | head -n 1)
```

Or more hackily:

```
r=$(($(head -128 /dev/urandom | cksum | cut -c1-10) % 2))
```

And also:

```
r=$(apg -a 1 -M n -n 1 -m 8 -E 23456789  | cut -c1)
```

As well as:

```
r=$((0x$(cut -c1-1 /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid) % 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

This script has no benefits over existing answers. Just for entertainment purposes...

Get one byte from `/dev/urandom` (although in general sending arbitrary binary characters to console is not recommended™ because it might give unexpected/confusing results):

```
head -c 1 /dev/urandom
```

And turn in into decimal number:

```
head -c 1 /dev/urandom | od -An -t u1
```

And get the remainder of its division by 2:

```
echo $((`head -c 1 /dev/urandom | od -An -t u1` % 2))
```